# C++ Template Copy Constructor Deep Copy

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, containers

I'm writing an generic Array class and overloading operators for convenience. I've gotten my Array<> object to hold other Array<> objects, but I'm having trouble overriding the * operator. I need to copy the left object, so my operator* code is this:

```
Array<T>& operator*(const double scalar) {
    return Array<T>(*this) *= scalar;
}
```

(operator*= has been overloaded and works).

I overrode the copy constructor as below:

UPDATE: New copy constructor:

```
Array<T> (const Array<T>& copyfrom) {
    size_=copyfrom.size();
    data=new T[size_];
    copy(&copyfrom.data[0], &copyfrom.data[size_], data);
}
```

My thought is that if the array were not generic but always filled with a primitive, this code would work. But I think there's something going on here because I'm using a template that's causing behavior I don't expect. The data array in the new "deep copied" Array acts like it's just a shallow pointer copy of the "copyfrom" data array.

How do I made this copy constructor work for both primitives and objects, using templates? Or, better yet, is there a way to overload operator* without worrying about copy constructors? Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the code for `operator*=`. I still think my problem lies in my use of the copy constructor, however.

```
Array<T>& operator*=(const double scalar) {
    for (int i=0; i<size_; i++)
        data[i]*=scalar;
    return *this;
}
```

EDIT: I realized that I was getting problems because I was ignoring the `size` of my inner arrays in my array of arrays. Things are more reliable now. Everyone's been really helpful, and I think I'm on the way to making this work. My `operator=` (which I hadn't overloaded; good catch, Michael) is now as below. It acts as expected, but I'm starting to get `malloc` errors in my program and I'm exploring why. Is there anything wrong with the memory management here?

```
Array<T>& operator=(const Array<T>& a) {
    if (this==&a)
        return *this;
    delete [] data;

    size_=a.size();
    data=new T(size_);
    copy(&a.data[0], &a.data[a.size()], data);

    return *this;
}
```

EDIT: I fixed the `malloc` errors! My methods are all working as intended now. The memory problems were coming because I had this method header:

```
template <typename T>
static Array<T> matrixSolve (Array<Array<T> > m);
```

I was taking an array of arrays by value. All sorts of problems. Took the array by reference and everything worked out. Thanks for the help, everyone!

Comment: @MichaelAnderson The code for `operator*` shouldn't return `this`. The call of `Array<T>(*this)` calls the copy constructor, which I've confirmed. Also, I don't get a compile error when I use `operator*=` if I make `operator*` const, so I must not be mutating `this`.

Comment: You are correct - I'll delete those comments.

Comment: Can you show us `Array<T>::operator=` ? When you're using `data[i]=copyfrom.data[i]` you are invoking the `operator=` for the data. If thats not defined you'll get the default one. So If you nest Arrays and Array doesn't have = then bad things will happen.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using `std::vector` or `std::array` for the `data` member? You'd then probably have the default copy constructor and assignment operators do the right thing.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I think you hit it; I'm nesting arrays and invoking `operator=` on an `Array<T>` object. That's probably a problem. I'm going to overload `operator=` and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Thanks for all your help. I wish I could accept comments as answers; if you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want your operator* member function to look something like this:

```
Array<T> operator*(const double scalar) const {
    Array<T> result(*this);
    result *= scalar;
    return result;
}
```

If you return an `Array<T> &`, then you will be returning a reference to a temporary which will be destroyed, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: You probably want to make that `operator*` const too.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: true -- changed

Comment: There is nothing bad about pulling together those three lines to one, as in the OP's original code; in fact I consider it more readable because you don't introduce the noise of declaring a temporary variable name and it's immediately visible that you're essentially doing "`*this *= scalar` with a backup".   It was just the return-by-reference and the missing `const` that was wrong.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I don't think that many people would agree. Using `(lhs *= rhs)` as an rvalue equal to `lhs` isn't that readable.